# How to send system path of image in HTML Link box in robot framework?

Tags: python, automation, robotframework

[image]

How to handle for upload an image in robot framework. Id for Choose box is //*[@id="campaignImage"]

Comment: Could you reword your question? At least to me it's confusing and I don't know what you are after. It would be even better if you add code you've tried and say where you got stuck.

Comment: I had an link field where I need to send the image path. So I stored image in Project folder. How could I send system path in robot framework. In above I attached image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you need is to send an absolute path to a field on a website.

What you need for that is:

- store the relative path in relation to your project dir in some variable
- get full path of your project dir
- use `SeleniumLibrary` for inputting the path into the input box

I guess you're asking more about first two points.

In RF, you can get the absolute path of the current dir from variable `${CURDIR}`. Assuming you always run your tests from the project dir, what you're looking for might be the following:

```
*** Variables ***
${path_to_image}=    \\Img_folder\\logo.png

*** Test Cases *** 
Log Absolute Path To Picture
    Log    ${CURDIR}${path_to_image}
```

This will log an absolute path to your image when you run the test from the project dir.

Of course, instead of `Log` keyword, you'd use [`Input Text`](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Input%20Text) which will fill in the input box on your site with the path.

Comment: I got the error  be Variable definition not found. Attached the screen pls check

Comment: Isn't it just your IDE showing you this error? When you actually run your test case, what happens? `${CURDIR}` is a builtin variable: http://robotframework.org/robotframework/2.9b2/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#operating-system-variables

Comment: One more field I have chose image section. How to upload an image

Comment: @MahendraVengalam: this has been asked many times, try to search for a solution first. If you get stuck on something, ask a new question, it's not really related to this one anymore.